Convert empty lists to nulls
I have a polars DataFrame with two list columns.
However one column contains empty lists and the other contains nulls.
I would like consistency and convert empty lists to nulls.

In [306]: df[["spcLink", "proprietors"]]
Out[306]: 
shape: (254_654, 2)
┌───────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ spcLink   ┆ proprietors                     │
│ ---       ┆ ---                             │
│ list[str] ┆ list[str]                       │
╞═══════════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│ []        ┆ null                            │
│ []        ┆ null                            │
│ []        ┆ null                            │
│ []        ┆ null                            │
│ []        ┆ null                            │
│ …         ┆ …                               │
│ []        ┆ ["The Steel Company of Canada … │
│ []        ┆ ["Philips' Gloeilampenfabrieke… │
│ []        ┆ ["AEG-Telefunken"]              │
│ []        ┆ ["xxxx…                         │
│ []        ┆ ["yyyy…                         │
└───────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘

I have attempted this:
# Convert empty lists to None
for col, dtype in df.schema.items():
    if isinstance(dtype, pl.datatypes.List):
        print(col, dtype)
        df = df.with_columns(
            pl.when(pl.col(col).list.len() == 0).then(None).otherwise(pl.col(col))
        )

But no change happens in the output; the empty lists remain as such and are not converted.

The output name of the when expression comes from the .then() branch - which in your case will be "literal". You would need .otherwise(pl.col(col)).alias(col) to explicitly keep the input name.


selectors.by_dtype to select all columns of type pl.List(pl.String).
list.len() to determine if list is empty.

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "spcLink": [[],[]],
    "proprietors": [None,["xxx"]]
}, schema={"spcLink": pl.List(pl.String), "proprietors": pl.List(pl.String)})

┌───────────┬─────────────┐
│ spcLink   ┆ proprietors │
│ ---       ┆ ---         │
│ list[str] ┆ list[str]   │
╞═══════════╪═════════════╡
│ []        ┆ null        │
│ []        ┆ ["xxx"]     │
└───────────┴─────────────┘

import polars.selectors as cs

df.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        cs.by_dtype(pl.List(pl.String)).list.len() > 0
    ).then(
        cs.by_dtype(pl.List(pl.String))
    )
)

┌───────────┬─────────────┐
│ spcLink   ┆ proprietors │
│ ---       ┆ ---         │
│ list[str] ┆ list[str]   │
╞═══════════╪═════════════╡
│ null      ┆ null        │
│ null      ┆ ["xxx"]     │
└───────────┴─────────────┘


It works but I don't understand why my attempt didn't.

cause in your example polars can't infer the name of the column and assigns literal to it as a name. It will work if you add .alias(col) at the end of Expr
